# Python. Добавление внешних модулей, чтобы работало у всех

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

У меня есть проект, залитый на гитхаб. Решил проверить, как он будет работать с другого пк, а питон мне написал, что мол модуль, добавленный в этот проект, отсутствует в системе. Как сделать, чтобы моя программа работала у всех без лишних действий?

Comment: Добавить в проект [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае обычно список зависимости распространю в файле requirements.txt. Для того что бы установить пакеты из этого файла нужно выполнить команду:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

Для создания файла из текущего виртуального окружения:

```
pip freeze --local > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Сразу не получилось. Чтобы установить, нужно ввести "pip3 install -r requirements.txt"

Comment: В Unix Like операционных системах да. В винде такой необходимости нет